# Selecting data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm try to select some data from my database but I'm stuck at one part. I'm not sure what to subsitute for (Last postID).

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table WHERE postID = (Last postID);
```

**Table:**

```
 name | postID
name1 | 1
name1 | 2
name1 | 3
name1 | 4
name2 | 1
name2 | 2
name2 | 3
name3 | 1
name3 | 2
name3 | 3
```

**Expected results:**

```
name1 | 4
name2 | 3
name3 | 3
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler way to accomplish what you want. Basically you just want to get one result per `name`, so just GROUP by that.

```
 SELECT
     name, MAX(postID) AS lastPostID
 FROM
     tbl
 GROUP BY
     name
```

Each `name` will form a result group, thus be unique, but be accompanied by the last postID. If they're sequentially indexed, the maximum postID will be the latest obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Your expected results differ from your problem statement, one has two columns, the other one.

But, the answer to your question is a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.name
FROM table t
WHERE t.postID = (SELECT MAX(t2.postId) FROM table t2);
```

This assumes that "last post id" means the one with the largest value.

Comment: That won't work since the last post ID won't always be 3. Some could be 3. Some could be 4. Some could be 5. If the largest value is 5, it'll only get the name with a postID of 5, and not the other ones.

Comment: @jessica . . . I don't understand your comment at all.  I think the question is pretty clear, and the sample data and desired results are quite clear.

Comment: Basically I need it to say something like, the maximum postID relevant to the distinct name.